# Use a parameter to determine which CTE/ Temp Table to return query results from?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a stored procedure that contains CTEs or Temp Tables to build things like base populations, do some calculations, return data at a granular level, and aggregate the granular level.

So CTE_Time_Between_Tasks has the following columns: Task_ID, Priority, Time_From_T1_to_T2, and Time_From_T2_to_T3. and CTE_Avg_Time_Btwn_Tasks that has columns: Priority, Avg_Time_From_T1_to_T2, Avg_Time_From_T2_to_T3. What I'd like to do is have some @OutputChoice variable (VARCHAR(3)) that that tells the query which CTE to use to return results from. I.e. returns the granular data from `CTE_Time_Between_Tasks` if `@OutputChoice = gra` or return the aggregated data from `CTE_Avg_Time_Btwn_Tasks` if `@OutputChoice = avg`.

The reason for this is so that when I'm using `EXEC StoredProcedureNameHere <OutputChoice>`, I can easily choose if I want to look at the granular data behind the scenes or the aggregated values for a summary view.

Currently, I have my query structured like this:

```sql
DECLARE @OutputChoice AS VARCHAR(3)

WITH CTE1 AS (...)
,CTE2 AS (...)
,CTE_Time_Between_Tasks AS (...)
,CTE_Avg_Time_Btwn_Tasks AS (...)
SELECT 
CASE WHEN @OutputChoice = 'gra' THEN (SELECT * FROM CTE_Time_Between_Tasks)
    WHEN @OutputChoice = 'avg' THEN (SELECT * FROM CTE_Avg_Time_Btwn_Tasks)
    ELSE NULL
    END AS RESULTS
```

I get an error of:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS, but I don't really understand what that means.

I can run both `SELECT * FROM CTE_Time_Between_Tasks` and `SELECT * FROM CTE_Avg_Time_Btwn_Task` separately without issue.

Comment: The error *is* telling you the problem you are trying to do a `SELECT *` for the value returned from the `CASE` expression and, presumably, your CTEs have more than one column  (otherwise why `*`) and more than one row. That's not a scalar value.

Comment: That makes sense, but is there a way to build this such that it can accept a table-based result?

Comment: Build dynamic sql depending on the parameter and then execute the query

Comment: UNION ALL the cte's instead. (Needs same number of columns, of compatible data types.)

Comment: Without seeing the queries (as you've obfuscated them) difficult to know but, perhaps, you just should be using `IF...ELSE` logic.

Comment: I would suggest separating the CTEs into separate procedures and decide which to call at the point where the parameter is currently being decided.

Comment: Making such a generic procedure is bad from both a performance perspective and an "understanding" perspective. Ideally you make SQL as straightforward and single purpose as possible for all the good reasons of performance, maintenance, low barrier for a new dev to understand etc. Its not like regular code where you want DRY code.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement* - so if you check the docs you'll see it can only return a scalar not an expression.

Comment: You would have better luck with performance splitting this into three procedures. The one you call from your code will then have logic to call either the details procedure or the aggregate procedure. But I would reconsider even that as it would make more sense to just use two procedures and have your code decide which one to call.